# Testing the sagemaker endpoint deployment locally

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

How to test the endpoint deployment in sagemaker locally using the sagemaker notebook instance?

The issue is that if we want to test the endpoint using the sagemaker studio notebook then it will take some time before it spins up the docker inference container depending on the instance. This can certainly hamper the development and process cycle!

Answer (score 3):

Create a LocalSession and configure it directly:

```
from sagemaker.local import LocalSession

sagemaker_session = LocalSession()
sagemaker_session.config = {'local': {'local_code': True}}
```

Now pass this sagemaker_session to your estimator or model